# Issues with small RecyclerView with EditTexts and Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a small list of almost 10 items (and this will not be greater than 20 in any case). It will not be changed after activity is created.

**My Current Setup:**

- I am using a `RecyclerView` for the list.
- I have a `Checkbox` and **2** `EditText` (say 1 and 2) in each list item.
- I do some calculations based on if checkbox checked and the value of EditText-1 and populate the new values to another EditText-2.
- On some cases user edits the Value of EditText-2 and calculations happen again and it will be populated in all other places including EditText-1 of for all the items.

**Problems solved:**

- However, in this situation I was facing issues with the TextWatcher called multiple times. I solved it with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860393/1820644
- Changing Checkbox values changing some random other checkboxes. Solved it using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549047/1820644

**Another Problem:**

Now, as data change of EditText-1 changes values for all other items of RecyclerView, I am calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` to reflect the changes after doing calculations. But this causes the `EditText` to loose focus. And it intends as all the views are recreated after `notifyDatasetChanged`. Even stable ids are also not useful in this situation. (There is bug related this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204277). The value is not even reflects and EditText looses it focus.

**What can I do?:**

- Is there any workaround? I am seeing strange changes in items values after setting stable ids.
- As the Items are fixed and no items are added and removed after onCreate, Using a scroll view with the container and adding items by manually inflating views in loop (and updating also will be ease, I think) will make my life a little easier?

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an array of objects to save the statuses of your `EditText` along with the values to be populated in your list. For example each of your items in the list might look like this class.

```
public class ListItemCustom {

    // Add some extra parameters to handle the state of the EditTexts
    public String textOfEditText1;
    public String textOfEditText2;
    public boolean focusEditText1;
    public boolean focusEditText2;

    // Contains original values of your list item
    public OriginalListItem mOriginalListItem;
}
```

Now take an `Array` or `ArrayList` of `ListItemCustom` custom and populate your items there inside `onCreate`. Then pass this list in your adapter and then handle the `EditText` and the values accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, don't call `notifyDatasetChanged()` when your data is changing instead call [`notifyItemChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) or [`notifyItemRangeChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) which will update only that view which has the changes and your focus will remain as it was.